# Implemention of Abstract in python

Tags: python

In python to implement an abstract class, we have to import the following:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
```

In the above import statement what is the purpose of abstractmethod?

If it is a decorator, what's the exact operation its performing?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod

Comment: Your question strongly suggests you haven't read the `abstractmethod` documentation (which others have already linked for you), since it _begins_ with the words, "A decorator".  That easily qualifies your question for a down-vote, since "This question does not show any research effort;" (taken from the down-vote arrow's mouse-hover text).  If, after reading the documentation, you still have a question --- a clear and potentially-helpful-to-others question --- about `abstractmethod`, that question will likely be much better received than this one was.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

> `@abc.abstractmethod`
> A decorator indicating abstract methods.
>
> Using this decorator requires that the class’s metaclass is [ABCMeta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) or is derived from it. A class that has a metaclass derived from ABCMeta cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and properties are overridden. The abstract methods can be called using any of the normal ‘super’ call mechanisms. [`abstractmethod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) may be used to declare abstract methods for properties and descriptors.